# What permission are required to select an existing event location in CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent, permissions, acl

We are using CiviCRM 4.7.19 with Drupal 7.56. When creating or editing a CiviEvent our super users can use an existing location from a drop down:

[image: Super user Event Location tab with choose location]

We also use another role in our organisation with more limited permissions but still enables event add/edit. However in the Event Location tab while they can enter an address the 'Choose Location' block is not visible:

[image: Editor user Event Location tab with no choose location]

What permissions need to be set to allow the choose location block to be visible when editing/adding a CiviEvent? (We use Drupal Access Control to set permissions for CiviCRM)

Answer (score 1):

If you're able edit an event, I don't think you need any additional permission to add existing location for an event.

The reason why you don't see an option could be because you haven't yet created any event location on this site? If this is the case, try adding a location for this event and then create a second event - you must be able to choose location on this newly created event.

Comment: Don't think it's that. Both screenshots are from the same event edit page but logged in with different accounts. Temporarily giving the lower user super admin rights reveals the choose location block but I'm struggling to isolate which permission it is. I tried unpicking the source code but permission handling wasn't apparent to me

Comment: Ok - as you have 4.7.19 installed, make sure you apply https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325 for event get api to work which is used in fetching location for events.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, I would first check these 3 permission - `access CiviCRM, access CiviEvent and view event participants`